# Show popup time delay in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popup

I used a Wordpress theme where a popup is build in.
The popup shows when click on this link:

```
<a href="#etheme-popup" class="etheme-popup">Nieuwsbrief</a>
```

So it activated with this id **etheme-popup**

Now i want trying the popup shows automatic after a delay of 2 seconds.
So adding this code snippet, but doesn't work:

```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#etheme-popup').show(); }, 2000);
  });
  </script>
```

Hope somebody can help me.

PS: Adding the code in theme's **functions.php**:

```
function popup_delay() {
  $newsletter_popup = '
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(\'#etheme-popup\').show(); }, 2000);
  });
  </script>';
  echo "\n" . $newsletter_popup;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'popup_delay', 20);
```

Comment: Are you sure the popup has that `id` when the page is loaded? You mention that "... it activated with this id...", so maybe that `id` is being asigned when you click the anchor (for the theme function that handles the popup). I've posted an answer that keeps the anchor and triggers its behaviour.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you.
At this moment not at home. I try this tomorrow, i hope this solution works.
If it works (or not) i'm adding a comment 

Comment: Yes, in popup's html this id is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the anchor is doing what you want (the behaviour is already handled by the theme), you can trigger the click event of that anchor...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('a.etheme-popup').trigger('click');
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you Iglesias.
Same for you.
Very happy with this solution ;-)